# Rails Server restart every time I make a change

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a module file that I need to use for my rails project. When I make a change to any Rails models, views, controller etc the server doesn't need to restart. but when I make a change in that module I need to restart the server.

The `module.rb` does not inherit anything from Rails classes.

**The structure is this:**

```
class_1.rb < class_2.rb includes module.rb
```

`class_1.rb, class_2.rb are also not ActiveRecord classes`.
They are all located in my models' directory.

My `config/enviroments/development.rb` file is correct, as it has this:

```
  config.cache_classes = false
```

Comment: which version of rails ?

Comment: You could try running this from "rails c" to see if cache_classes is set like you believe it is: APP::Application.config.cache_classes where APP is the name of your application.

Answer (score 1):

**Update: For rails 3.2.9 this should work right out of the box !**
Here is what i tried and it works without restarting the server:

```
# ../models/a.rb
class A
  include SomeModule
  def test
    " test:a"
  end
end

# ../models/b.rb
class B < A
  def test
    super + " test:b"
  end
end

# ../models/some_module.rb
module SomeModule
  def call_test
    test + " test:module" 
  end
end

# ../controllers/home_controller.rb
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @i = B.new.call_test
  end
end
```

---

You can place this inside your application.rb when your module doesnt live within the autoload paths:

```
# Autoload lib/ folder including all subdirectories
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/your_module_folder/**/"]
```

Comment: I added these lines just to make sure:
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/models/**/"]
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/**/"]
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/models/**"]
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/**"]
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/models/*"]
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/*"]

Comment: where is your module located  ?